# shower arm leaking when not in use

Tags: plumbing

I have a shower stall (no tub). The shower head leaks water when not in use. I replaced the posi-temp cartridge and it still leaked. Then I installed a vacumm breaker which screws into the shower arm, then the shower head screws into it. That slowed the leaking water a lot, but it still leaks a slow drip. Any Master Plumbers out there who can help please.
Thanks a lot, Armando

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of the leak? How much/hour does it leak? Is the leak continuous, or just after a shower?

Comment: Could it just be leaking because some water gets left in the line after you shut off the shower at the valve? Have you tried not using the shower for more than twenty-four hours to see if it still leaks? My shower head drips randomly for hours after a shower, I assume due to weird siphoning effects on water that is left between the valve and the shower head after I turn off the shower.

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the cartridge a set it exactly the same way, you may have set it to the wrong "off" position by duplication of the "leaking" one. The temperature limiter also sets the stop point on many diverter.

**See "stop tube kit"**
[image]
[soilco.co](http://soilco.co/faucet-parts-names/faucet-parts-names-faucet-parts-large-size-of-replacement-anatomy-shower-faucet-parts-names-door-valve-faucet-replacement-parts-bathroom-sink-faucet-parts-names-tub-faucet-parts-names/)

**Test**

To test if this is the issue, remove the hardware and very slowly turn the cartridge and try to find off dead center.

**If this fails**

If this doesn't solve the problem then it's likely that the diverter body has worn or has developed sediment. It may need to be thoroughly cleaned or replaced.